# How can I Print a POS Memo from thermal printer with Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-material

**I design a shop management application with angular 7 & node js. I want to print the customer sell memo template with Thermal Receipt printer when i click print() function. Please Help for this problem..**

[Print Like This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIlKR.jpg)

```
<ng-template #mytemplate>
<div id="print-section">enter code here
    <h2 class="live-memo-title">Customer Memo</h2>

    <table class="memoTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Items</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Discount</th>
        <th>Sub-total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let report of saleReport">
        <td>{{report.product.name}}</td>
        <!--<td>{{report.product.company}}</td>-->
        <td>{{report.product.salePrice}}</td>
        <td>{{report.quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{report.discount}}</td>
        <td>{{report.totalSale}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="total-cost-view">
      <h1>Total = {{getTotalCost() | number : '1.2-2'}}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Are you asking once you use window.print() to open a print dialog how to format it to print on your thermal printer correctly?

Comment: did you resolved it ?

Comment: @divya I want a soluition too